# Joomla 2.5 - own plug-in has no effect (installed & enabled successfully)

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I want to write the plugin that simply displays "PAGE MOVED" text instead of page.

I have made a folder `myPlugin`.

Inside, I put `myPlugin.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="2.5" type="plugin" group="system">

    <name>myPlugin</name>
    <creationDate>Creation date</creationDate>
    <author>Your name</author>
    <authorEmail>Your e-mail address</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>Your website</authorUrl>
    <copyright>Copyright information</copyright>
    <license>All rights reserved.</license>
    <version>Version of the plugin</version>
    <description>Description of the plugin</description>

    <files>
       <filename plugin="myPlugin">myPlugin.php</filename>
    </files>

</extension>
```

And `myPlugin.php`:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class myPlugin extends JPlugin{
    public function __construct(& $subject, $config){
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
        $this->loadLanguage();
    }

    public function onAfterRoute() {
         die("PAGE MOVED"); //no effect
    }

    public function onAfterRender() {
        die("PAGE MOVED"); //no effect
    }

    public function onBeforeRender(){
        die("PAGE MOVED"); //no effect
    }
};
```

I made a `myPlugin.zip` from it.

Than I have installed it via Joomla Extension Mannager (success), than enabled it (success).

But when I go to any of my pages, I see no effect of `myPluing`.

**What else I have to do to see the effect?**

I have disabled cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is not named correctly. For Joomla to call a method of your plugin's class, it has to follow the standard naming convention. Based on your xml file, you have created a system plugin, so the class should be named as follows:

```
class plgSystemMyPlugin extends JPlugin{
```

That should make it work (i.e. die often)!

Comment: Thanks! Now my plug-in works (cause a lot of death to pages :P ).